# ANTLR4 for Java. How to display errors in lexical analysis

Tags: java, antlr4

How can you display a list of errors (if any) during lexical analysis.
I tried the following method, but my output is [org.antlr.v4.runtime.ConsoleErrorListener@1026c84c].

The code I wrote:

```
private static String errorsOutput(String code) {
    Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(new ANTLRInputStream(code));

    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);

    return ""+lexer.getErrorListeners();
}
```

Main class:

```
String code = "public class Main {public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println("Hello, world")}}";
System.out.println( errorsOutput(code) );
```

There is no sign in this example
[;] and I need the program to display this error

Comment: Usually you would trap errors with a try/catch -- I don't see yours. And what you're printing out is the `toString()` returned from the error listeners. Doesn't make sense to try to print out the listener objects, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is not lexical analysis, but syntactic analysis.

This is how you add a custom error listener and collect messages:

```
String source = "public class Main {\n" +
        "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
        "        System.out.println(\"Hello, world\")\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";

Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

parser.removeErrorListeners();

final List<String> errorMessages = new ArrayList<>();

parser.addErrorListener(new BaseErrorListener(){
    @Override
    public void syntaxError(Recognizer<?, ?> recognizer, Object offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, String msg, RecognitionException e) {
        errorMessages.add(msg);
    }
});

parser.compilationUnit();

System.out.println("errorMessages: " + errorMessages);
```

Note that the snippet above will display the message `mismatched input '(' expecting '.'` because at this location:

```java
System.out.println(
//                ^
//                |
//                '-- here
```

it cannot match a println statement because of the missing `;` so it then tries to match another `.` to complete a `methodInvocation`, which also fails. That is just how the grammar is structured, not much to do about that (besides rewriting large parts of it).

If you parse this:

```java
String source = "public class Main {\n" +
        "    public static void main(String[] args) {\n" +
        "        foo()\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "}";
```

then you do get the message: `missing ';' at '}'`