# Antlr4 not failing on partial expression

Tags: java, antlr4

**update**
solution in here:
[ANTLR4 for Java. How to display errors in lexical analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544255/antlr4-for-java-how-to-display-errors-in-lexical-analysis)

I'm using antlr4 in java.

I have a .g4 file that I can clean down to (I know it doesn't make sense like this)

```
exp :
    num opr num;

opr :
    '+';

num :
    '-';
```

So -+- is a valid expression:

[image]

But I'd expect this to get an error:

[image]

I'm not getting a hit in the visitErroNode nor any exceptions.
How/where can I get the fact that the expression is not complete?

Comment: The parser will produce an error, but emits this on the STDERR and (tries to) recover and continue parsing. What you want to do is override the default error listeners: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64544255/antlr4-for-java-how-to-display-errors-in-lexical-analysis

Comment: Btw, if the linked Q&A doesn't answer your question, please edit your question and explain why it doesn't work for you: I'll then reopen this Q.

Answer (score 0):

`antrl` give the proper answer, means `-+-` is accepted. Now, maybe it have no sense in math way but it's a valid expression.
Definition is `<VT><VN><VT>` : `T-terminal, N- non_terminal`.
If you put `-` as VT fine then, up to you. It doesn't have to be a number.
But semantically you have to know what `-` behave is, when processing AST (abstract syntax tree).
Say other : `syntactically` ok based on your def(`antrl` say that) but when processing means `semantically` (could be fine also if do a proper processing for `-`). Imagine saying `0` instead of `-`.

Comment: no sure i understand what you mean, or maybe i wasn't clear in the question.
-+- is valid and should be. but -+ is not valid, because it has to be -+-. what i doen't understand is why i'm NOT getting an error when using the Parser+TreeWalker.

if looking at a math expression, i want to get an error for '4+' because it's missing the right-side operand.

Comment: -+ is not valid, but antrl can construct partial AST (till the end of invalid input which can be processed). Now, not sure how you can see output errors (invalid_parsing) should look on docs or maybe check the duplicate answer.(as far as i see on other comment need just to redirect the error). When parsing_input the AST (tree) is constructed (even on invalid-input ... which can be accesed also) _ syntactic analyze.(error -> partial AST till err) Processing AST means semantic analyze (second step after successful parse input, means 1+1 -> 2). Hope to be helpful if needed ...